# Bitcoinjs-lib как создать транзакцию перевода биткоинов с кошелька на кошелек?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin

Задача, вроде бы, не сложная. Написал вот такой код, согласно примеру из документации BitcoinJS: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/transactions.js#L46

```js
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
var key = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy')
var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder();
tx.addInput("d18e7106e5492baf8f3929d2d573d27d89277f3825d3836aa86ea1d843b5158b", 1);
tx.addOutput("12idKQBikRgRuZEbtxXQ4WFYB7Wa3hZzhT", 149000);
tx.sign(0, key);
console.log(tx.build().toHex());
```

и он, вроде бы, работает. НО у меня складывается ощущение, что он слишком простой и в нем не хватате элементов.

Что нужно для правильного перевода биткоинов с одного кошелька на другой?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в этой либе, но все что нужно для перевода биткоинов, это: приватный ключ, айди транзакции с выходом, номер выхода, конечный адрес и количество. Все это есть в вашем коде.

Comment: Да, все это есть. Но все средства, которые останутся на кошельке отправятся майнерам. Как сделать чтобы можно было указать сколько перевести на другой кошелек, сколько отдать майнерам и сколько оставить?

Comment: А `149000` это разве не количество, сколько вы передаете на `12idKQBikRgRuZEbtxXQ4WFYB7Wa3hZzhT`?

Comment: в доке написано, что если на кошельке 15000, а перевожу 12000, то 3000 пойдет майнерам.  // (in)15000 - (out)12000 = (fee)3000, this is the miner fee

Comment: Что бы указать сколько перевести майнерам, вам нужно знать, сколько находится на выходе предыдущей транзакции. Это уже вам нужно самим думать, откуда такую информацию получать.

Comment: Можете показать пример правильной транзакции с одного кошелька на другой (из той библиотеки, которую вы используете)?

Comment: В меня нет примеров, я знаю только теорию. На самом низком уровне биткоина нет понятия кошельков (или адресов), есть только входы/выходы транзакций. Если вы хотите оперировать с ними, вам нужно разобраться во всем этом. Или же пойти самым простым путем, держать запущенным bitcoind, и использовать RPC. Проблема с фул нодой в том, что нужно очень много места на диске + нагрузка на процессор/диск заметная.

Answer (score 1):

Этого кода достаточно. Но, как уже было замечено в комментариях, в данном случае вся неизрасходованная сумма уйдет в качестве комиссии майнеру. Чтобы указать кошелек для сдачи (или добавить еще получателя), нужно просто добавить еще один выход:

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
var key = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy')
var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder();tx.addInput("d18e7106e5492baf8f3929d2d573d27d89277f3825d3836aa86ea1d843b5158b", 1);
tx.addOutput("12idKQBikRgRuZEbtxXQ4WFYB7Wa3hZzhT", 149000);
tx.addOutput("1bdjdy73jgb8723fb8Vdv9e7G743is7kgd", 1000); // еще один получатель
tx.addOutput("1Jdg387fgau8ghGdvdo87267fg672gf9ff", 200000); // кошелек для сдачи
tx.sign(0, key);
console.log(tx.build().toHex());
```